# How to fetch data from SQL database to combo box - C#

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, combobox, radio-button

I have a radio button & combo box like this:

[image]

If the user chooses the radio button either single or double, the combo box automatically fetch the data (room number which is single-type if I choose single-type). I already have stored procedure like this.

```
create procedure viewRoom
@IDBranch varchar(5),
@NoTypeRoom varchar(5)

as

select NoRoom
from MsRoom
where NoTypeRoom = @NoTypeRoom
and IDBranch = @IDBranch
and AvailabilityRoom>0
```

What should I do, so the fetched data can be shown in the combo box every time I choose the radio button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to use `cmd.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure`

```
SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand("viewRoom", conn);
cmd.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;
da=new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
ds=new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
for(int i=0;i<ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;i++)
cmbItems.items.add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].tostring()); //way to put table in combo
```

Try to use this kind of code.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: then how to put it from the tables to the combobox?

Comment: really sorry, mistakenly written cmd at last line, see my edit

Comment: so the cmbItems refers to the name of my combo box?

Comment: yup, i have also put comment over it.

Answer (score 1):

You can Populate Combobox  like this:

```
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "YourColmName";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "YourFied"; //Field which you want set the value of combobox 
comboBox1.DataSource = PopulateCombo(NoTypeRoom,IDBranch) // variables
```

Here in this case may be your Value and label are same, but in other case you need to specify

---

```
Public DataTable PopulateCombo(string NoTypeRoom,string IDBranch)
{
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("viewRoom", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NoTypeRoom", NoTypeRoom);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDBranch", IDBranch);
SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
dap.Fill(ds);
return ds.Tables[0];  
}
```